# Typescript infer with type mapping is unexpectedly dropping `undefined`

Tags: typescript, generics, undefined, type-declaration

In TypeScript, I have a function that takes a generic object whose values are all an instance of a generic class (`MyClass<T>` in the code sample below). I want the return value to be an object with the same keys but whose types are the corresponding `T` types.

Using TypeScript's `infer` keyword I've gotten this to work; however, if one of the `T`'s is a union with `undefined` then the `undefined` seems to be dropped.

How can I get the `undefined` to carry through to the type of the corresponding key in the returned object?

Code sample:

```
class MyClass<T> {
  type = "MyClass";
}

type MyClassType =
  | MyClass<string>
  | MyClass<number>
  | MyClass<string | undefined>

interface MyClassInstanceByName {
  [name: string]: MyClassType
}

type ValueTypeByMyClassInstanceByName<T extends MyClassInstanceByName> = {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends MyClass<infer U> ? U : never
}

function transformer<T extends MyClassInstanceByName>(input: T):
    ValueTypeByMyClassInstanceByName<T> {
  throw new Error("not implemented");
}

function test() {
  const result = transformer({
    shouldBeString: new MyClass<string>(),
    shouldBeNumber: new MyClass<number>(),
    shouldBeStringOrUndefined: new MyClass<string | undefined>(),
  });

  const isAString: string = result.shouldBeString;
  const isANumber: number = result.shouldBeNumber;
  const isStringOrUndefined: string = result.shouldBeStringOrUndefined;

  // The type of `result.shouldBeStringOrUndefined` above is inferred to be
  // `string`, but I want it to be inferred as `string | undefined`.
}
```

I've tried a whole bunch of different permutations of the type declarations, but each time I get something that works it "drops" the `undefined` or produces something incorrect, like `never`. I also tried to understand the difference between an optional property (i.e. a field name suffixed with `?`) and a property whose type is `| undefined`. I tried to figure out some magic to mark the properties with `undefined` in their type union as optional with `?` but haven't quite figured that out.

Comment: [I can't reproduce your issue](https://tsplay.dev/mbnb9m).  Are you not using `--strictNullChecks` or something?

Comment: :facepalm: You're right. I didn't have `strictNullChecks` enabled. Enabling `strictNullChecks` yielded the expected behavior. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

As [@jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz) suggested, the fix was to enable `strictNullChecks`.